# Next.js Image component breaks Background Slide Show

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am currently converting my React app to Nextjs. I have a React component that is supposed to display a background slide show on mobile devices. It works without using the `<Image />` component, but breaks when adding `<Image layout='fill' />` which is what I want since the image should take up the entire screen. Width is managed by React's functional state hook btws.

#### Background Slider

```
const transform = {
    transform: `translateX(-${width * count}px)`,
    transition: 'transform 0.6s ease-in-out',
    position: 'relative',
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100vw'
}

if (width <= 800) {
    return (
        <>
            {mobileImages.map((image, index) => {   
                return (
                    <div style={transform} key={index}>
                        <Image 
                            src={image} 
                            alt='idk'
                            layout='fill'
                        />
                    </div>      
                )
            })}
        </> 
    )
```

What I get instead is all 6 images squished into the initial viewport and the slideshow scrolling to whitespace. Kind of lost with whats happening here.

[image]

Comment: Seems like removing display: flex gets rid of the sizing problem, but still quit fix the slideshow

Comment: So its due to the preset span css that wraps the image when using the <Image /> component. Not sure if theres a way around that